# Automate "Add Feature" in a specific program, not a Windows feature

Tags: windows, application

Autodesk provides [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/downloads/caas/downloads/content/civil-3d-country-kits-for-united-kingdom-ireland.html) manual process for adding a "Country Kit" to their Civil 3D product, but I am hoping to automate the process, ideally with PowerShell. Autodesk is  useless from a support standpoint, so I am hoping someone can point me at some information, or verify that there is no generic way to address this as it is program specific. My guess is that is true, but I would like to verify before I give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic way to address this as it is program specific.

Comment: I figured as much, but good to have it verified. Thanks!